# Texture Binding : OpenGL + OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

I am trying to read an image from a file and map it as openGL texture. OpenCV is reading the image right and showing it in a window created from there. but the texture mapping part is not working. Can't find out why. My code is given below:

```
int InitGL(GLvoid){

    try
    {
        Mat img = imread("aaa.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
        if (&img != NULL)
        {
            namedWindow("Show Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            imshow("Show Image", img);
        }
        glGenTextures(1, texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, img.cols, img.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        img.release();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        cout << "My Msg: " +e.msg << endl;
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);               // enabling smooth shader
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // black background

    glClearDepth(1.0f);                    // depth buffer setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);               // enable depth testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                // the type of depth test to do

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);     
    return TRUE;                           // initialization went ok
}

int DrawGLScene(GLvoid){


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);                   // Move Right 3 Units
    glRotatef(rotationQuad, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        // Front Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        // Back Face
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        // Top Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        // Bottom Face
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    // Right face
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    // Left Face
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glEnd();                           // Done Drawing The Quad

    rotationQuad -= 0.15f;
    return TRUE;                                 // Everything Went OK
}
```

The window created from OpenCV is showing the image. It is for debugging and testing whether the image is read correctly or not. The cube was supposd to be textured. But it is not showing any texture on it.

Comment: please use: `if (! img.empty())`  for checking, the address of a Mat will be *always* valid.

Comment: That part is working fine. Texture binding part is not working... :(  @berak

Comment: whats the resolution of your image? maybe it must be a "power of 2" or some similar limitations?

Comment: Try to call `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before `glTexImage2D(...);`. OpenCV stores images in contiguous memory segment by default.

Comment: Also OpenCV uses BGR format, so you should change source format to `GL_BGR`.

Comment: @jet47 : I am giving a 512x512 image now. but still not working. can you give me a link to some sample code using opencv and opengl, please.

Comment: There is some OpenGL interoperability support in OpenCV. To enable it you need to add `-DWITH_OPENGL=ON` to OpenCV cmake configuration (the OpenGL support is not available in the pre-built binaries). There is also a small sample: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/gpu/opengl.cpp

Comment: using : glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]); instead of glGenTextures(1, texture); solved the provlem. but aren't they actually same? they have the same pointer address. don't have a clear idea. Can you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:
        `glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);`
instead of:
        `glGenTexures(1, texture);`
solved it.